# Does this set of locks imply table lock and if so is it avoidable?

Tags: sql-server-2008, locking

I have a query on SQL Server 2008 that when using sp_whoisactive with get_locks = 1 has the following locks open....

```
<Object name="my_table" schema_name="dbo">
  <Locks>
    <Lock resource_type="KEY" index_name="pk_mypk" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
    <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
    <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="pk_mypk" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
</Object>
```

I understand the Key and Page lock but am unsure what the Object one is. Is that a table lock? If so why did it bother taking key and page locks as well? Are there ways to work out why a particular query that is only touching a small set of rows would use a table lock, I'm guessing it's lock escalation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference:

- [Lock Modes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

See above reference for more details.

Intent = Used to establish a lock hierarchy. The types of intent locks are: intent shared (IS), intent exclusive (IX), and shared with intent exclusive (SIX).

> Intent Locks
>
> The Database Engine uses intent locks to protect placing a shared (S)
>   lock or exclusive (X) lock on a resource lower in the lock hierarchy.
>   Intent locks are named intent locks because they are acquired before a
>   lock at the lower level, and therefore signal intent to place locks at
>   a lower level.
>
> Intent locks serve two purposes:
>
> - To prevent other transactions from modifying the higher-level    resource in a way that would invalidate the lock at the lower level.
> - To improve the efficiency of the Database Engine in detecting lock    conflicts at the higher level of granularity.
>
> For example, a shared intent lock is requested at the table level
>   before shared (S) locks are requested on pages or rows within that
>   table. Setting an intent lock at the table level prevents another
>   transaction from subsequently acquiring an exclusive (X) lock on the
>   table containing that page. Intent locks improve performance because
>   the Database Engine examines intent locks only at the table level to
>   determine if a transaction can safely acquire a lock on that table.
>   This removes the requirement to examine every row or page lock on the
>   table to determine if a transaction can lock the entire table.

Comment: The above answers your question.  There's an intent exclusive lock placed at the table (object) level, that has to be there in order for SQL to get a lower level exclusive lock.